# Since I am a videographer I have a question

Tags: practical-islam, sharia, islamic-basis, muslim-practices, islamic-scholar

would it be haram for me to film events such as weddings or places where alcohol is consumed and music played if I don't take part?

Answer (score -1):

salaam,
No, you are there doing your job. As long as you don't take part in consumption, its should be fine. :) My coworkers for instance, go to happy hour a lot, and as long as I am not taking part in it, I know that I am not committing sin. :)
Best,
Michelle

Comment: How sure are you of this? In Hanafi, you're not even supposed to attend a non-Muslim wedding: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/16873

Comment: Also, attending such events literally means to invite shaitan towards your path.

Comment: But I am not enjoying anything I am just flying a drone